# Detecting focus on a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried looking on this on the official angularjs documentation but they offer no explantions on elemental events
--------HTML---------------

```
<my-input-container>
 <input />
</my-input-container>

<my-input-container>
 <select>*****</select>
</my-input-container>
```

-----------JS-----------------

```
mymodule.directive("my-input-container",function(){
   //****
   //when <my-input-container> is focused or any elements inside it is
   //i will add a class="my-input-focused"
   //when it loses focus,I shall remove the class="my-input-focused"
   //***
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 mymodule.directive("my-input-container",function(){
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // Focus
        element.bind('focus', function(){
          // Add class
        });
        // Lost focus
        element.bind('blur', function(){
          // Remove class
        });
      }
   }
 });
```

For value of input in this directive:

```
mymodule.directive("my-input-container",function(){
    return {
      scope: {
        inputValue: '=',
      },
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // Focus
        element.bind('focus', function(){
          // Add class
        });
        // Lost focus
        element.bind('blur', function(){
          // Remove class
        });
      }
   }
 });
```

`template.html`:

```
// something
  <input ng-model="inputValue" name=""/>
// something
```

View:

```
<my-input-container input-value="inputValue">
  // Something
</my-input-container>
```

`inputValue` variable from your controller.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, one more question...if the input inside <my-input-container> has ng-model, how do I know if the ng-model value has changed and how do I retrieve it's value?

Answer (score 2):

you should bind `focus` event to directive.

```
 mymodule.directive("my-input-container",function(){
    return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        element.bind('focus', function(){});
    }
    }
 });
```

Comment: so how do I know that it lost focus? or the elements inside it has lost focus?